# What can I do if I lost my iCloud PIN code?

Tags: macos, passwords, icloud

Is there a way I can retrieve my PIN code used to lock my MacBook Air via iCloud though my Apple ID?

I just can't seem to remember the code and need to unlock it but can't seem to find the correct Apple resource.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way would be to take your Air to the Apple store. They will do it for you.

If you want to hack it yourself, here is a tutorial: [How to: Unlock System Lock PIN Code - MacRumors Forums](http://forums.macrumors.com/showthread.php?t=1438822)